# Load app icon from xcassets on OS X

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsimage, osx-elcapitan, nsdocktile

I can't load another app icon into `NSImage`. I tried to use both asset name and name of the particular file but image is always `nil`.

```
let image = NSImage(named: "Alerted")
//let alertedDog = NSImage(named: "Alerted128x128.png")

image?.size = NSSize(width: 128, height: 128)
NSApp.applicationIconImage = image
NSApp.dockTile.display()
```

Any thoughts?

In packaged file I see only standard AppIcon.icns and there is no Alerted.icns...

Comment: As far as I've read, another app's icon is read only...

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of icons. Additional should be of generic type.